# i'm trying Restart line numbering in reledpar from just one of the many pstart

Tags: line-numbering, reledpar

I'm working with reledpar on a twoside prose text (this means that i have facing pages to achieve not columns or verses). So, divided in many "chunks" to get facing pages. I numbered text lines, but i don't know hot to restart numbering from just one (the beginning of second act) of many pstart.
in fact \lineation* can be done only with pstart, section or pages arguments.

And if i write at this specific pstart \endnumbering and \beginnumbering (for both sides) works but when Overleaf compiles cannot find anymore the left side text.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{changepage}


\firstlinenum{5}
\linenumincrement{5}

\begin{document}

\newpage

\begin{pages}

\begin{Leftside}
\selectlanguage{italian}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
  %act I
  %scene I
\pend 
.
.
\pstart
  %act I
  %scene II
\pstart
.
.
\pend
 %only here i need restart line numbering
\pstart
%act II
%scene I
\pend
\end{Leftside}

%the same for Rightside
\end{pages}

\end{document}
```